# Is mtk-su safe? Is it actually temporary?

Tags: rooting, malware, mediatek

mtk-su which helps mediatek mtk-65** based phone owners to basically gain a "temporary" root. My question is, if it was actually temporary as it claims, and if it actually doesn't persist after each system reset or reboot. The other day I scanned the file on virustotal, and the engines detected it as a malware.

mtksu xda forum https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/amazing-temp-root-mediatek-armv8-t3922213/amp/

Comment: Such applications should always be detected by virus scanners because they use exploits to gain root access - hence they bypass existing security measures. That is by definition malicious - but in this case expected - behavior.

Comment: No, exploits aren't safe. Yes, exploits are temporary, to be fixed one day.

Comment: malware can use it, even if just temporary that is enough to replace system apps. you should flash stock ROM